# Using short time zone names

Tags: c#, timezone, datetime-format

I just stumpled upon a date with the following format `2011-11-10 13:34:38 CET`.

Parsing the date is quite easy. But I can't figure out how to handle the time zone. The struct used for `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` doesn't seem to contain any field that I can use for the lookup.

Do I have resort to a static lookup dictionary or are there a built in way to handle the `CET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [TZ4Net](http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm) will help you. Given `DateTime` you can convert from `CET` time zone to UTC with the following code:

```
OlsonTimeZone tz = OlsonTimeZone.GetInstance("CET");
tz.ToUniversalTime(date);
```